# Notation I can't understand in Quake source code (C)

Tags: c, header, quake

I was taking a look at the Quake 1 GPL Code and I came across various similar header files, the purpose or use of which I don't seem to understand. They look like tables of some sorts and are structured like this

```
{1, 0},
{1, -1},
{1, -2},
{1, -3},
{1, -4},
{1, -5},[...]
```

Without anything before or after them. I understand they define something but I've never come across this kind of notation in C.
You can read one of the header files I'm referring to [here](http://www.koders.com/c/fid053BE3136F9FB2B1EDE5F4D9010B679E212FC78D.aspx).

My question is: what are those...things? The ASM is actually giving me less problems than that stuff.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are probably multi-use includes. They can be used like so:

```
struct {int y; int y;} points[] = {
#include <points.inl>
};
```

Answer (score 8):

The contents of a header do *not* have to be valid C; the C preprocessor will insert them wherever the `#include` directive is found, such as in the middle of a struct initialization in another source file. As long as it's valid C by the time it actually gets to the compiler, that's all that matters.

Answer (score 3):

They can be used to initialize arrays.

You could use them like this:

```
int array[N][2] =
#include <header_file>
;
```