# What could be the purpose of a header file with raw data?

Tags: c, opengl, header-files, raw-data, quake

Decided to check out some code other than my own, [Quake I](https://github.com/id-Software/Quake) was the choice. The first file I click on is filled with nothing but raw data and the only comments are the GPL. I am guessing it is an array containing normal vectors? Regardless of what its purpose was, what confuses me is what it is doing in a header file [anorms.h](https://raw.github.com/id-Software/Quake/master/WinQuake/anorms.h). I am wondering what could be the purpose of doing this?

The other source, actual code, feels fairly complicated to me. As a novice programmer I probably just need to spend more time at it.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4344640/2712809)?

Comment: It's initializing the Anorms.  Isn't it obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing by the looks, it's indeed a normal array used somewhere in the game.

In older days, pretty much every game content was hardcoded; now you can simply open a file and load the data, because the HDDs (and more often SSDs) got so much faster.

Older games were also compiled as plain C executable; in modern IDEs such as Visual Studio (or pretty much anything, really), you can easily compile arbitrary data into the .exe in form of *resources*.

All that being said, it's simply legacy cruft and I shouldn't be very concerned with it.

---

Sample usage:

```
struct Vec { float x,y,z };
Vec arr[] = {
    #include "anorms.h"
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I am just curious how it could possibly be used. Judging by the syntax it is being used in compiling, but the only way I figure it could be read is through file i/o. I must be wrong?

Comment: @Leonardo there you go.

Comment: Wow I knew there was something crazy like that. Thanks I learned something, mission complete!

Comment: As a note, I would not have named the file `.h`, because this is a fixed convention for header files with related expectations, which obviously led to the question. Something like `.inc` for include may be better here.