# How to convert C program code into char[]?

Tags: c, string, c-preprocessor, opencl, embedded-resource

I'm writing an OpenCL kernel which is then compiled to run on GPU. Kernel code is contained in a *.cl file, which is then read by the application. It's inconvenient to always copy the *.cl file into application folder. Much better solution would be, if the kernel code could be parsed and converted into C char[] string during application compilation. Then there would be no need to provide the original *.cl file to the application's user.

My question therefore is: How can I in the most convenient and simple way convert OpenCL code into a C string, which will then be used by the application, when the application is compiled? Is there any way to do it using C preprocessor or do I need to run a Python, Perl or similar script to do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that **C code could be generated**. You can generate the C code containing the initialization of your array.

So you can have an (and you can even find some existing) utility which generate some C code like

```
0x23, 0x34, 0x02, 0x33,
```

and use appropriately `#include` with that file. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26843374/841108) answer.

That utility could be a simple C program, a simple Python script, or some [Unix pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) (combining `hd` or `od` with `cut` or `awk` or `sed`, etc...) or something else.

You'll better configure suitably your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool to regenerate such a header when needed. If you use [`make`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), you'll just add a few lines (some recipe) in your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile).

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a C string only the byte array. C string is sequence of characters terminated by zero.

Use online tool to convert binary file to the C array for example http://tomeko.net/online_tools/file_to_hex.php?lang=en